# LINQ to SQL GroupBy Max() lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Please help me convert this to a lambda expression

```
SELECT [UserID], MAX(Created) Created
FROM [UserHistory]
WHERE userid IN (14287)
GROUP BY [UserID]
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here's what I have so far.

```
List<T> list;  //list is populated

table.Where(x => list.Select(y => y.ClientId).Contains( x.UserID))
                    .GroupBy(x => x.UserID)
                    .Select(x => new { x.UserID, x.Created })
                    .ToList();
```

When I add the GroupBy, my Select says there's no definition for x.UserID and x.Created.

Comment: When I add the group by, my select breaks.  Does the group by eliminate all the other fields or something?

Comment: Remember, after `group by` you have `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TGroupingKey, TYourOriginalClass>>` instead of your original `IEnumerable<TYourOriginalClass>`. Guys below show you practical examples of the fact.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var userIDs = new[] {14287, };

var results =
dataContext.UserHistories
.Where(user => userIDs.Contains(user.userID))
.GroupBy(user => user.userID)
.Select(
     userGroup =>
         new 
         {
             UserID = userGroup.Key,
             Created = userGroup.Max(user => user.Created),
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from history in context.UserHistories
                where ( new[] {14287} ).Contains(history.userID)
                group history by history.UserID into g
             select new 
             {
                 UserId = g.Key,
                 MaxCreated = g.Max( x => x.Created)
             };
```

Comment: The original post asked for lambda

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your edit, as I said in comment, in `.Select(x => new { x.UserID, x.Created })`, `x` is *no longer* a `UserHistory`, it is `IGrouping<int, UserHistory>`(1), which does not have `UserID` and `Created` properties, but only `Key` property, which is an user id and implements `IEnumerable` to enumerate all items for the given key (user id).

Use @DaveShaw snippet as it is the most correct one and most efficient.

(1) I assume `UserID` is `int`.